# How to solve Mismatched anonymous define() module?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page and I'm trying to add an external library:

```
<script async src="somepath/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

The web page contains already some other libraries added by my framework (which is Oracle Apex) and that I don't control.

However I'm getting the error : (screenshot)

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

I'm not a JavaScript guy, so I don't know how to add this library without getting this error.

Can anyone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to load it with require instead of with `script`

Somewhere you should have an `requirejs-config.js` file. There you need to add your script:

```
var config = {
   map: {
      sweetalert: "js/sweetalert"
   }
}
```

The key is your name, and the value is the path to the script
Now you can use it like this:

```
require(["sweetalert"], function(){
   swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
});
```

This should be enough

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the mapping in the config file. Where shoud I add `require(["sweetalert"], function(){});` please ? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasCarlton somewhere in your page. I would say somewhere at the top

Comment: And I should keep `<script async src="somepath/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>` right ?

Comment: @ThomasCarlton no, you shouldnt. by writing `require(["sweetalert"], function(){});` require.js will load it for you

Comment: Oh thanks. I've followed your sugestions but when using the library I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined`. Basically some of the library global variables are not declared. Is there any way I should "initialize" the library so that it declares everything it need ?

Comment: @ThomasCarlton `Swal` is this a variable of an library?

Comment: Yes. Normally when I add the library using `<script async src="somepath/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>` in a page that contains only this library, every thing works fine. All the declarations/initialization are done by the library. By the way the library is [link](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation)

Comment: i forgot 1 thing, you need to put your code inside the `function() {}`. I have edited my answer

Comment: I really appreciate your time but it's not working :(. Still getting the error : VM1531:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

Comment: @ThomasCarlton one thing you can do is to put swal into the function argument `function(swal) { ... }`. Open your dev tools with F12, go to network TAB and check if your sweetalert script gets loaded